# android unable to get contacts from some phones

Tags: android, contacts

I wrote an app that needs to read the contacts from the user's phone. Since I've put it on the market, a few users have told me that my app cannot read their contact list (it pops up an error message saying it can't get the contact list).

For roughly 80% of the users, everything works fine, but others have this problem.

In my MainActivity, I call the method: `GetContacts()`

If that method returns no contacts, then I call: `GetContacts2()`

If the app still can't get the contacts, then it pops up the error message. Below are the two methods I'm using. Some of the phones, this doesn't work, are Droid X2 and HTC Incredible.

I'm also setting the required API level to 8 in my manifest, so that eliminates older phones. I also do not have log files from these users.

NOTE: I've removed extra code that simply puts the contacts in an array for simplicity's sake.

Any ideas on why these methods don't work on all phones?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Mark

```
private void GetContacts()
{
    try
    {
        Context context = getApplicationContext(); 
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null); 

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
        { 
            contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)); 
            contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)); 
            hasPhone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)); 

            if (Integer.parseInt(hasPhone)==1) 
            { 
                Cursor phone = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
                null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId,null, null); 

                while (phone.moveToNext())
                {   
                    phoneNo = phone.getString(phone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    phoneType = phone.getString(phone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
                }
            } 
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
}   

private void GetContacts2()
{
    try
    {
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        if (cur.getCount() > 0) 
        {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) 
            {
                contactId = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                contactName = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) 
                {
                     if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) 
                     {
                         Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", new String[]{contactId}, null);
                         while (pCur.moveToNext()) 
                         {
                            phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                            phoneType = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
                         } 

                         pCur.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: For one, you probably shouldn't just swallow the exceptions. Probably something is failing and you're getting an exception but now you can't really see what's going wrong because you threw them away by having an empty catch.

Comment: Did you get any solutions ?....
Facing similar issue in Droid MINI

Answer (score 0):

I agree. Exceptions are definitely not meant to be tossed aside. They're exceptions; they indicate that something is seriously wrong and needs to be looked at. I recommend you at least log them, so that users that run into the problems can send you a LogCat. If you don't want your users to have to go through that trouble, write data to a file on the SD card (public), so that they can access it and send it to you.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I'll change the code so that the errors are captured. That will hopefully help in figuring this out. IS there a reason why my code wouldn't work though?

Comment: You guys gave me a good idea. Instead of having the users deal with log files and all that, I'll just create an email intent with the error message as part of the email message. That way, the user just has to send an "auto-generated" email with the error message already in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
  //declaration   
Cursor cursor;
int cNameIndex = 0;
int cNumIndex = 0;
String [] arrPosDrawn= null;


//oncreate  
TelephonyManager telMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        int simState = telMgr.getSimState();
                switch (simState) {
                    case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT:
                        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                ContactList.this);

                        alert.setMessage("Please insert Sim card.")
                                .setTitle("Alert")

                                .setNeutralButton("OK",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                            public void onClick(
                                                    DialogInterface dialog,
                                                    int which) {
                                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                            }
                                        }).show();
                        break;
                    case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY:
                        cursor = refreshContactsCursor();
                         //contacts.setAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(this));
                        break;  
                }
//function
public Cursor refreshContactsCursor()
    {
        cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        startManagingCursor(cursor);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        cNameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME);
        cNumIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DATA1);
        arrPosDrawn = new String[cursor.getCount() - 1];
        for (int j=0; j < arrPosDrawn.length; j++) 
        {
            arrPosDrawn[j] = "";

        }
        return cursor;  
    }
```

Comment: I implemented this, gave new new version of the app to a few people who were having this problem and it didn't help. It still can't read their contacts. And they are using SIM cards. There's nothing weird with their setups on their phones. Any other ideas?

Comment: UPDATE: So what seems to be the problem is that the check for phone numbers isn't working. The line "if (Integer.parseInt(hasPhone)==1)" is always false. No errors either....strange....

Comment: You can get the device on which it is failing and  see what is is returning for hasPhone  . SInce its working for some cases it must be device specific